# Try catch inside or out?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

What's better and why:

**This**

```
public void Main()
{
    SomeMethod();
}
public void SomeMethod()
{
  try
  {
     // code
  }
  catch(Exception)
  {
  }
}
```

or this:

```
public void Main()
{
    try
    {
        SomeMethod();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends. What is the contract for the method? I voted to close as "Not Constructive". Also, empty catch is **ick** most of the time.

Comment: @pst - Contract for the method? What do you mean?

Comment: Q: What's better?  A: "chocolate".  Chocolate is *clearly* better than "strawberry" ;) IMHO...

Comment: Contract for the method means what does the method do, and what exceptions might it throw?  You should only catch exceptions that you know how to handle, so without talking about what exceptions there might be and how they might be handled, it's hard to discuss the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: "catch the exception at the *lowest* level that knows how to handle it."

Answer (score 2):

There is a idea that you should be catching exceptions closest to where they occur (i.e. as high up the call stack as possible/appropriate). A blanket exception handler isn't typically a good idea because its drastically reduces the control flow available to you. Coarse-grained exception handling is quite importantly, but not a reasonable solution to program stability. Unfortunately, many beginner developers think that it is, and take such approaches as this blanket try-catch statement.

Saying this, if you have utilized exception handling properly (in a fine-grained and task-specific manner) in the rest of your program, and handled the errors accordingly there (rather than just displaying a generic error box), then a general try-catch for all exceptions in the Main method is probably a useful thing to have. One point to note here is that if you're getting bugs caught in this Main try-catch, then you either have a bug or something is wrong with your localized exception handling.

The primary usage of this try-catch with Main would be purely to prevent your program from crashing in very unusual circumstances, and should do hardly any more than display a (vaguely) user-friendly "fatal error" message to the user or just be left blank, as well as possibly logging the error somewhere and/or submitting a bug report.

*Credits: [Noldorin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44389/noldorin)*

Answer (score 2):

See [Exceptions and Exception Handling (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx) for guidance on exception handling in C#.  [This interview](http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html) with Anders Hejlsberg is also informative.

The relevant guideline here is:

> Do not catch an exception unless you can handle it and leave the application in a known state.

Generally, an exception should not be caught unless it can be properly handled.  This could be either `Main` or `SomeMethod`, depending on what is coded.  For instance, `Main` might include a general catch statement to handle general exceptions (and, for instance, write an error message to the console); but `SomeMethod` might be able to recover from certain exceptions and catch those.

Generally, `catch {}` (exception swallowing) should be avoided; a caller that cannot handle an exception should simply allow it to propagate upward.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule about which one is better. You can use both methods. The deal is you need to have the code that is most likely to throw an exception inside `try` and this applies to all programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Let say the next happens:

You want a valid message for each failure.

```
public void Main()
{
    try
    {
        SomeMethod();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

The above will be less informative, than catching each `try` inside `SomeMethod()`, so even so there is no difference, I will suggest to catch small actions that might fail, to provide useful data about the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you catch the exception in SomeMethod before it goes above and might get lost due to no immediate code visibility on the eyes

One very important thing is please try to catch the specific exception first rather than anything

e.g.

if SomeMethod is doing some string to number conversion then try to catch FormatException first and put the Exception class for anything else

Answer (score 0):

I think, customizing will be the best way to throw more understandable exceptions at the lowest level.

first define your custom exception class

```
public class SomeException : Exception {}

public void SomeMethod()
{
  try
  {
     // code
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  { 
      throw new SomeException ("an error in somemethod",e);
  }
}
```

now, you will catch more clearly exception at anywhere.